# keras: 98% of accuracy but the NN always predicts the same. What could be the cause?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensor

We have the following problem training a DL model to predict loan scoring (classifing into 0,1 or 3).

These are the steps:

## **step1: Create new column "scoring" (the output)**

```
conditions = [
(df2['Credit Score'] >= 0) & (df2['Credit Score'] < 1000),
(df2['Credit Score'] >= 1000) & (df2['Credit Score'] < 6000),
(df2['Credit Score'] >= 6000) & (df2['Credit Score'] <= 7000)]
choices = [0,1,2]
df2['Scoring'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

## step 2:preparing training

```
array = df2.values
X = np.vstack((array[:,2:3].T, array[:,5:15].T)).T
Y = array[:,15:]
N = Y.shape[0]
T = np.zeros((N, np.max(Y)+1))
for i in range(N):
  T[i,Y[i]] = 1

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, T, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

## step 3: Topology

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(80, input_shape=(11,), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(80, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

epochs =200
learning_rate = 0.00001
decay_rate = learning_rate / epochs
momentum = 0.002
sgd = SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum, decay=decay_rate, nesterov=False)
ad = Adamax(lr=learning_rate)
```

## step 4: training

```
 epochs = 200 
 batch_size = 16 

 history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), nb_epoch=epochs, 
 batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.1) 
 print ('fit done!')
```

**metrics**

365/365 [==============================] - 0s 60us/sample - loss: 0.0963 - acc: 0.9808
Test set
  Loss: 0.096
  Accuracy: 0.981

[accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tok9Z.png)

## step5:prediction

```
text1 = [1358,1555,1,3,1741,8,0,1596,1518,0,0] #scoring 0 
text2 = [1454,1601,3,11,1763,10,0,685,1044,0,0] #scoring 1 
text3 = [1209,1437,3,11,199,18,1,761,1333,1,0] #scoring 2

tmp = np.vstack(text1).T
textA = tmp.reshape(1,-1)

tmp = np.vstack(text2).T
textB = tmp.reshape(1,-1)

tmp = np.vstack(text3).T
print(tmp)
textC = tmp.reshape(1,-1)

p = model.predict(textA)
t = p[0]
print(textA,np.argmax(t))


p = model.predict(textB)
t = p[0]
print(textB,np.argmax(t))

p = model.predict(textC)
t = p[0]
print(textC,np.argmax(t))
```

**Problem : The output is always the same in the prediction !!!**

> [9.9205679e-01 3.8634153e-04 7.5568780e-03]
>     [[1358 1555    1    3 1741    8    0 1596 1518    0    0]] 0 --- scoring 0
>
> [0.9862417  0.00205712 0.01170125]
>     [[1454 1601    3   11 1763   10    0  685 1044    0    0]] 0 --- scoring 0
>
> [9.9251783e-01 2.5733517e-04 7.2247880e-03]
>     [[1209 1437    3   11  199   18    1  761 1333    1    0]] 0 ---- scoring 0

¿what can be the reason of this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extremely unbalanced dataset. A nice way to look at it is: if always predicting 0 gets you to 98% accuracy, then it is quite risky (or it has to be very obvious) to say that something belongs to a different class. Every pattern that the NN may find that makes any of the minority class different from the majority class (0) has to be pretty unique because even with small overlapping, the cost of not predicting 0 is too high.

Consider this example: You have a dataset with two classes, A and B, both of which follow a normal distribution. Class A has mean 1 and std 1, class B has mean 3 and std 0.1. You have 1,000,000 samples of class 0 and 20,000 samples of class 1, so predicting always A gives you 98% accuracy. All samples of class B will lie between 2.743 and 3.257 with 99% confidence. Between those values, class A is expected to have 29,300 samples, so the cost of predicting any observation as class B is making an error in 29,300 A samples, but the cost of predicting everything as A is to only have an error in 20,000 B samples.

Here's how that example looks graphically:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get A and B
A = np.random.normal(1, 1, 1000000)
B = np.random.normal(3, 0.1, 20000)

# Count the number of observations in A for each B
B.sort()
a = A[np.logical_and(A >= B.min(), A <= B.max())]
a = [(a<i).sum() for i in B]

# Plot results
plt.plot(B, np.arange(B.shape[0]), label='Class B')
plt.plot(B, a, label='Class A')
plt.ylabel('Count of samples')
plt.xlabel('Values')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Unbalance example]

See this article about balancing datasets: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer! you are right. Using ML to solve it with the same dataset the accuracy and predictions so i didn´t think this could be a problem. were right but with DL needs a homogenized  datasatet